# Akeneo Use of tags to dynamically add content to product descriptions

Tags: akeneo

In Akeneo, when editing a product, we wonder if it's possible to make use of tags within description fields to dynamically add content.

So for example, product description field:
`This is a test description of product {{product_name}}`

Where {{product_name}} will fill in the name of the product.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKuDi.jpg)

We couldn't find anything regarding this functionality in Akeneo's documentation, hence the question.

Already searched via Google/StackOverflow to find if the use of tags is possible within Akeneo, no luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively no. But you have a bundle: https://marketplace.akeneo.com/extension/text-template-bundle that does exactly that.